# Textfield should becomesfirstresponder after entering four digits in another textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, first-responder, becomefirstresponder

I have two UITextfields as follows,

[image]

If the user enter 4 digits in the first textfield, then the second textfield should becomesfirstresponder. I have tried below code,

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
  int num = [textField.text length] - range.length;
  if(textField==pin && num ==4)
  {
    [cpin becomeFirstResponder];
  }
}
```

This works like, the user has to enter the fifth digit. I want the second textfield to becomes responder after entering four digits in the first UITextfield. How to do that?

Comment: Change the num == 4 to num == 3?

Comment: @CW0007007, If I make num==3, fourth letter is typed on the cpin.

Comment: Change it to + range.length then 4 should work, you are omiting the newly typed character from the num count. AS the textField text doesn't update until after that method returns.. Also you need to return YES; from that method.

Comment: @CW0007007, Pl elaborate more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to omit the RANGE parameter..

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
  if([textField.text length] == 3 && ![string isEqualToString:@""]) // Verify that replacementString is a digit and not a backspace
  {
    textField.text = [textField.text stringByAppendingString:string];
    [cpin becomeFirstResponder];
    return NO;
  }

  return YES;
}
```

Comment: @shai there is a serious error if we add four digit in first textfield then control goes to next textfield but we again manually click on first textfield and delete textfield content only one digit is removing and control going to next textfield...Please make it correct.

Comment: @AshwinMangrulkar, Thanks for your point. yes it's an issue in the above code. But I'd made the textfield entry type as secure type entry. So, If I delete one text all the texts gone away.

Comment: @NAZIK then its ok with that particular scenario but for generalize code not working.

Comment: @AshwinMangrulkar, actually he mentioned to check the backspace hit in the answer. Added code for that. :)

Answer (score 1):

*Untested as I don't have access to IDE atm*

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    int num = [textField.text length] + range.length;
    if(textField==pin && num ==4)
    {
        [cpin becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Or i'm sure you could just use `int num = string.length` or get rid og the int num all together and just use: `if (textField == pin && string.length == 4)`

Comment: +1 for your suggestions, `AppendingString:string` done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
          int num = [textField.text length];
          if(textField==pin && num ==4) {
            [cpin becomeFirstResponder];
          }
         return YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. this should work

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)strin
{
    int num = [textField.text length] - range.length;
    if(textField== pin && num ==4)
    {
        [cpin becomeFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Hope this helps.